# Execution of while with getchar function

Tags: c

If I have the following:

```
while (getchar() != 'y')  
   printf("some...");
```

I want to know if `while` tests chars only when the buffer is empty.

So if I input

```
abcdy[enter]
```

then after the `[enter]` is `while` executed?

Has `getchar` itself a `while` to test when enter is pressed?

Comment: Did you try running the program?

Comment: @minitech, yes, it works. Why?

Answer (score 2):

getchar is a blocking call, i.e. it will wait until you give it input.

Comment: So after I flush the buffer the while is executed... and process all the chars I entered...

Answer (score 1):

"Try it and see" can tell you what something does, but not what it is *supposed* to do.

In this case, the behavior of the `while` loop is evident from the code: it will continue until `getchar` returns the value `'y'`; it will not stop when getchar returns `'\n'`, or `EOF`, or anything other than `'y'`.

For the behavior of `getchar` itself, reading from a terminal, there are essentially three cases to worry about:

1. If something has been typed and not yet read, `getchar` will return the next character.  `getchar` itself does not care about line boundaries; <kbd>ENTER</kbd> causes it to return `'\n'`.  However, the terminal (emulator) may only feed input to the program in whole lines, depending on what mode it's in, so if the user has typed `abc` but not yet <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you may actually be in state 3 (below).
2. If the terminal has been closed (or pseudo-closed by typing <kbd>^D</kbd>) and all input up to that point has been read, `getchar` will return `EOF`, which is not equal to any character value.  It will do this over and over again until the application stops calling it.  Your code is **buggy** in that it does not check for `EOF`: it will become stuck in the loop forever if the terminal is closed.  (This may not be obvious from running the program normally, because closing a terminal causes immediate delivery of a `SIGHUP` signal, which will (by default) kill the process.  Try running it as `./a.out < /dev/null` to see the infinite loop.)
3. If everything that has been typed has been read, but the terminal is still open, `getchar` will not return until more typing happens or the terminal is closed.  The underlying `read` system call is said to *block*, meaning that the kernel takes the CPU away from your process until more input becomes available (and lets other programs execute; it is not a spin loop waiting for input, as one might imagine if one were used to `kbhit`/`getch` under DOS).

Comment: *“Your code is buggy in that it does not check for EOF: it will become stuck in the loop forever if the terminal is closed.”* Won’t it generally terminate from a hangup signal?

Comment: @minitech Yah, I was maybe trying to gloss over irrelevant details too hard.  See edit.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` blocks at the system level.

While `getchar()` is blocked, you can press keys, move the mouse, switch windows, have a beer, ..., ....

`getchar()` will unblock when you type ENTER at the correct window. Then your program will see all the keystrokes in succession, up to and including the ENTER.

Comment: No, it will unblock on *any* keypress. You are thinking of `gets`

Comment: I don't use `gets()`! It's not `getchar()` that blocks, it is the Operating System that blocks (and buffers the characters).